# Local ring after adjoining a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the ring of $p$-adic numbers, $\Phi _p(x)$ the cyclotomic polynomial and $\zeta$ be a $p$-th root of unity. So $\zeta \not \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and we get 
$$ \mathbb{Z}_p[X]/\langle\Phi_p(x)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \zeta \mathbb{Z} \oplus \dots \oplus  \zeta^{p-2} \mathbb{Z} $$
a free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module of rank $p-1$.

> Let $\pi := \zeta-1$ and I want to know how to see that $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta]$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta]$.

My idea is to use the obviously fact that $\Phi _p(\pi +1) =0$ and the extension formula $ \Phi_p(x + 1) = p + \binom{p}{2}x + \binom{p}{3}x^2 + \dots + \binom{p}{p - 1} x^{p - 2} + x^{p - 1} $.

From this I can conclude that we have following inclusions:
$p \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] \subset \pi \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta]$
and $\pi^{p-1} \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] \subset p \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta]$

It's obviosly that it would be enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta] /  \pi\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta]  \cong \mathbb{F}_p$ and that every maximal ideal $M \subset \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta]$ contains $\pi$ but unfortunately I haven't a idea how to realize this two steps using the information above...

Answer (score 3):

$\Phi_p(\pi + 1) = 0$ tells you that

$$ \Phi_p(x + 1) = p + \binom{p}{2}x + \binom{p}{3}x^2 + \dots + \binom{p}{p - 1} x^{p - 2} + x^{p - 1} $$

is the minimal polynomial of $\pi$. What does that imply about $(\pi\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]) \cap\mathbf{Z}_p$? Which ideal is that?

Comment: If  $\Phi_{p}(x) = \frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$ then $\Phi_{p}(x+1) =\frac{(x+1)^p-1}{x}  
 = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} x^k {p \choose k+1}$

Comment: D you mean that from $\Phi_p(\pi + 1) = 0$  and $ \Phi_p(x + 1) = p + \binom{p}{2}x + \binom{p}{3}x^2 + \dots + \binom{p}{p - 1} x^{p - 2} + x^{p - 1} $ I can conclude $(\pi\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]) \cap\mathbf{Z}_p = 0$? But why does it hold?                                                                                                     Futhermore I don't see the next step...

Comment: @KarlPeter No $(\pi\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]) \cap \mathbf{Z}_p = p\mathbf Z_p$.

Comment: ups ok yes that's understandable ... but what I have to do next?

Comment: @KarlPeter Think. You now have to think.

Comment: unfortunately no idea :(

Comment: @KarlPeter I feel uncomfortable giving you any more hints because I don't know how your professor feels about getting help on your assignment. You can try asking your professor again or perhaps going through relevant portions of your notes.

Comment: Ok another attempt...  I know that $\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]^x = {\zeta ^j+p\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]}$, so it would be enough to show that $\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta] \backslash \mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]^x \subset\pi\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta] $. If I show that $\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta] = p \mathbf{Z}_p$, right?

Comment: @KarlPeter Yes.

Comment: Ok. There remaining two questions: Is my assumption that $\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]^x = {\zeta ^j+p\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]}$ true?                       
And the second one: How can be concluded from the fact that $\Phi_p(x + 1)$ is a minimalpolynom of $\pi$ that the equation $(\pi\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta]) \cap\mathbf{Z}_p = p\mathbf{Z}_p$ holds?